# While using cx_freeze, when running the exe it doesn't load

Tags: python, pygame, cx-freeze

As the title should suggest, I am having some problems. I am using Pygame and Python 3.3, and when trying to run my compiled script it spits out a black screen, and no error in console. This program works in Idle, but will not work in the EXE

Here is my setup.py

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable


exe=Executable(
     script="BackedGrid.py",
     base="Win32Gui",
     )

includes=[]
excludes=[]
packages=[]
setup(
     version = "1.0",
     description = "None",
     author = "Brandon Danyluk",
     name = "Backed Grid",
     executables = [exe]
     )
```

If you have any questions about my main program, please do ask. I am not good at providing details without any questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had issues when compiling my program with cx_freeze and pygame as well.  The fix I used was to add this to my main code:

```
try:
    import pygame._view
except:
    pass
```

For some reason it needs this module however only in exe form.  If you try to `import pygame._view` normally it will throw an error.  I have no idea if your setup file is correct either.  I just used the basic one and filled in the areas etc.  Ask any questions below.

Also see this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10045791/cx-freeze-executable-doesnt-work-with-pygame?rq=1) and the other problem is [here](http://pygame.org/wiki/Pygame2exef).

Comment: I am afraid that didn't work. But, I tried another cx_freeze thing, and it said I am missing something from pygame. pkgdata.py it is missing

Comment: You could also try manually looking in the pygame folder and copy that specific file to the app location.

Comment: Never mind, I have read the error fully now, and it says I am missing the font - freesansbold.ttf

Comment: Thank you for this, it fixed it. If only I could say that was the answer